# Removed element shows different between chorme and ie

Tags: javascript, html

This is the example page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outerDiv"><div id="innerDiv"><input type="checkbox"></div></div>
    <button type="button">Delete</button>
    <script>
        var inner = document.getElementById('innerDiv');
        console.log(inner);

        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('outerDiv').innerHTML = 'hello world';
            console.log(inner);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

when click the `Delete` button, `outerDiv` will change innerHTML, then console the `inner` value

in `chrome`

```
<div id="innerDiv"><input type="checkbox"></div>
```

but in `ie`

```
<div id="innerDiv"></div>
```

so the variable `inner` value are different in `chrome/ie`

It seems that `ie` browser will remove `innerDiv` content but not in `chrome`

Comment: You do not close the input tag. `<input type="checkbox" />`

Comment: Apart from not closing the tag as @A1rPun has stated, the console output for me in IE and Chrome is the same. What versions of IE/Chrome did you test in?

Comment: @A1rPun as long as it's not  XHTML,there is no problem at all.self closing tag in html5  is just syntax sugar. it has no meaning anymore

Comment: @A1rPun thank you for your answer, but close the input tag, also have this problem

Comment: @Yoink `IE11/Chrome41`

Comment: @Yoink do you click the `Delete` button, then console the `inner` value?

Comment: @A1rPun http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Comment: @huang.xinghui I didn't. I noticed as soon as I posted my second comment - I blame it being too early.

Comment: @suish the link is awesome